GPG Encrypting Via CLI output as .pgp rather than .gpg
Got a command that encrypts all files in a folder with our public key.
However, it saves the files as .gpg and the requirement is to output as .pgp.
Using the GUI you just append the name from .gpg to .pgp.
I've tried renaming the output but I'm just getting .gpg.pgp.
My current command:
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe" -ArgumentList "-r "public key email" -e Path\TO\FILE\$fileName" 

Where are you getting or setting $fileName? Can you test as test.pgp in place of $fileName and then check the output? If that works, it is really simple, just need to understand how $fileName is created, and then use $($_.basename).pgp or something like that—might need to enclose full path with double quotes though. Testing using a static file name first will confirm that simple name of the extension will suffice on the decrypt (and encrypt too I suppose).

Maybe something like this would work though too Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe" -ArgumentList "-r", "public key email", "-e", "Path\TO\FILE\$fileName", "--output", "Path\TO\OUTPUT\$fileName.pgp" 
